# Razor pages date input month and day switch around on submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I have a date input field on my Razor page where the month and day switch around every time the form is submitted. Obviously I do not want this to happen but I can not work out why it is.

So 11/10/2019 becomes 10/11/2019 then 11/10/2019 again. The form will also set the date parameter to null if I enter a date that would be invalid in the American format. e.g. 15/11/2019.

This is for a U.K. intranet page so I want the dates to always processed in day month year format. I have tried setting the culture to en-gb where it looks like it needs to be set but this does not seem to have helped.

I am using .net core 3.0.

My date definition (cshtml.cs)

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime MinDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Today;
```

my cshtml

```
<form asp-page="./ReferralIndex" method="get">
    <div>
        <p>
            Min Date:
            <input name="minDateIn" value="@Model.MinDate.ToShortDateString()" type="datetime"/>
            Max Date:
            <input type="datetime" name="maxDateIn" value="@Model.MaxDate.ToShortDateString()" />
            <input type="submit" value="Go" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

my culture settings in startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-GB");
                    options.SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("en-GB") };
                });

            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
            cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "£";

            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

            var supportedCultures = new[]
                                        {
                                            new CultureInfo("en-GB"),
                                        };
            app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
                                           {
                                               DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-GB"),
                                               SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
                                               SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
                                           });
        }
```

Comment: Prefer using ISO date format `2019-11-21T10:53:48.931Z` it has more compatibility and has less gotcha in parsing. 12/12/2012 this can mm/dd/yyyy as well as dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 2):

I managed to stop this behavior by changing the parameter for my dates on the OnGetAsync function from Datetime to string. This meant that they came in exactly as they were typed and I could then convert them to dates within the correct culture.

```
public async Task OnGetAsync(string sortOrder, string MinDate, string MaxDate)
        {

            if (MinDate!= null)
            {
                this.MinDate = Convert.ToDateTime(MinDate);
            }

            if (MaxDate!= null)
            {
                this.MaxDate = Convert.ToDateTime(MaxDate);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This walkaround works. I've raised [one issue in GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/17324) if you're interested.

Comment: Turns out that is a behavior by design. See this [thread](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/17324#issuecomment-557599437) and [this one](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/15829)